# How to do Groovy string interpolation with ordered parameters & nested substrings at the same time?

Tags: string, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, string-interpolation

I'm using Groovy for Jenkins pipelines and I want to create email template strings. The issue, is I want to have one string nested in another one, while also having ordered parameters. I want something like this:

```
# To use if job aborts/ends early
def shortEmail = """|Title: %1$s
                    |Link: %2$s etc.
                 """

# To use if the job is able to finish to completion
def longEmail = """|${shortEmail}
                   |
                   |Build Results: %3$s
                   |Test Results: %4$s etc.
                """
```

I tried:

1. **sprintf** with ordered params (ie. %1$s) (example above) 
   This would almost be perfect but using ordered parameters like %1$s don't work on GStrings ("") since they seem to raise a MissingPropertyException.
2. **SimpleTemplateEngine** 
   This solution allowed me to specify the parameter ordering I would like with the use of bindings, but I don't think I can use nested strings here. This is because if I use a GString rather than a regular String so that I can nest the shortEmail variable, then a MissingPropertyException will be raised for the other variables that are stored in ${} when the string is initialized.

```
def longEmail = """|${shortEmail}
                   |
                   |# These bindings below would raise an Error
                   |Build Results: ${BUILD_RESULTS}
                   |Test Results: ${TEST_RESULTS} etc.
                """
```

Comment: for #1 escape every `$` that you don't want to be processed as gstring: `%1$s` -> `%1\$s`.

Comment: for #2 you could bind any kind of parameters. for example array and access it like this: `${indexed[0]}`. also it you are going to define template in code - use triple single quotes - then it will be a plain string.

Comment: Thanks. Using the escape character allows me to do both methods (1) or (2)

Answer (score 0):

We can use the escape character, ie:

**sprintf**:

```
def shortEmail = """|Title: %1\$s
                    |Link: %2\$s etc.
                 """
def longEmail = """|${shortEmail}
                   |
                   |Build Results: %3$s
                   |Test Results: %4$s etc.
                   |Title Again: %1\$s
                """
printf(sprintf(longEmail, [
               'My Title', 'My Link','Some Build', 'Some Tests'
]))
```